# Counting elements in array and creating UILabels and UIImage iOS6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

I`m trying to implement the style of the Label-Image-Label etc.. in UItableviewCell, each row might have 3 or 4 or 5 labels with image between them. The text for the labels are stored in plist as array/dictionary ,keys are airprort1 airport2 etc.

I`m stuck at setting the cells and labels and image programmatically.

Tried with storyboard yet couldn`t figure the logic.

Here is my code so far:

```
#import "ShowLabelTVC.h"

@interface ShowLabelTVC ()

@end

@implementation ShowLabelTVC
     @synthesize flights;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"flight" ofType:@"plist"];
    flights = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", flights);

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return flights.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TagCell";
    TagCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TagCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    //for (int i = 0; i < flights.count; i++)
    //{
    //  cell.sec1Label.text = [[flights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"airport1"];
    //  if(i != flights.count - 1)
    //  {

    //  }
    //}
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Cameron what i want to acomplish is to have each cell show the correct amount of labels seperated by an image. 
For example:

**CELL1:**

```
Airport1 Image Airport2 Image Airport3 >
```

**CELL2:**

```
Airport1 Image Airport2 Image Airport 3 Image Airport4 >
```

Etc.

The data come from a plist array with dictionary as follow

```
Root:
    Flight1
         Airport1:"kwi"
         Airport2:"cai"
         Airport3:"kwi"
    Flight2
         Airport1:"kwi"
         Airport2:"bkk"
         Airport3:"mnl"
         Airport4:"bkk"
         Airport5:"kwi"
     Flight3
         Airport1:"kwi"
         Airport2:"jed"
         Airport3:"kwi
```

So i need to make uilabels programatically with an uiimage inbetween each label horizontally!!
And here were i'm stuck..
I don't have much reputation to attach an image of the final result i want to accomplish..

Comment: You're not going to get any help here unless we have a clear understanding of what you're trying to do and what's not working. All we know is you want to iterate over an array and set a bunch of labels to have the text in the array... We don't understand where you're having trouble.

Comment: With this data from plist you want to have 3 cells, first cell with 3 labels and 2 images, second one with 5 labels and 4 images and third cell with 3 labels and 2 images. Is it right?

Comment: Stas thats correct, i want to show as many labels in a cell as there in the plist array seperated by an image of a plane. I'm stuck at the for loop logic and adding uilabels side by side programatically by knowing only the first label position.. Thanks in advance.